# What object is nil here?

Tags: objective-c

In the following code I'm curious to know what object is being set to nil in the:

-(void)ViewWillAppear:(BOOL) method. Is self being nil'ed? or are all the objects in the

-(IBAction)showCurrentTime:(id)sender method being nil'ed, or are both being nil'ed?

```
-(IBAction)showCurrentTime:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (!formatter) {
        formatter = [[ NSDateFormatter alloc ] init ];
        [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    }
    [timeLabel setText:[formatter stringFromDate:now]];

}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self showCurrentTime:nil];


}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where timeLabel is being initialized? I assume this is an IBOutlet wired up to a text field on your display?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything being set to `nil`. If you are referring to the `sender` parameter, what is happening is `nil` is being **PASSED** as the sender object. This is not assigning any variable to `nil`. In your example, sender is never used, so `nil` has no effect.

However, if that parameter was used, you'd get the default behavior of passing messages to nil. That is, if the call is void, nothing happens, if it returns an object, nil is returned, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the line `[self showCurrentTime:nil];`, then it's simply sending nil because the method requires the `sender` parameter. If there are no cases when you need the sender (even if you are using the method from Interface Builder) then it's OK to remove the ":(id)sender" part of the method name.